# Answers to be filled in by default with an expression doesn't work in QFIELD

Tags: qgis, qfield, default, forms, values

I have set up a project in QGIS with default expressions which takes data from other fields previously filled in and automatically generates a value. It works fine when filling a form into QGIS but it doesn't work while filling a form into QFIELD. Does anyone knows why and how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you be so kind and describe this point *" it doesn't work ..."* more in details? Like what kind of error do you get, your expected result, your efforts and ideas etc.

Comment: Imagine i am filling a form with 3 fields and the third one is the sume of the first and the second, then i set a default expresion for the third field into the attribute form in QGIS, thus, after insterting the first and the second number i click the box to insert the third one and automatically generates the sume. Well, whenever i try to do the same thing in QFIELD using the same project, i insert the first and the second number and then i click on the third box and nothing happens. I have to do it manually as the default expresion doesnt work and nothing is automatically generated.

Answer (score 1):

Applying default values on update in "real-time" [like we have it in QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/#feature-update-depending-widgets-real-time) is not (yet) supported in QField.

But a generally used workaround for this case is QField's *fast editing mode*. It saves changes immediately and updates the other fields. And this leads to the behavior you are looking for.

[image]

Update:
In QField version 2.x.x live update will be supported. Check it out on the current Beta version.

Comment: I don't want to raise a new issue on the tracker yet (still trying things out), but this seems to be non-functional for me in 4.2.2. Is there any reported issue for other people trying to have default values applied in real-time according to expressions referencing other fields in the layer?

Answer (score 0):

This may help: When creating the form, fill out the expression for the summed field using `current_value()` to pull the values from each of the prior fields to create the new summed value.